# getter property in merged destructured object cannot interpret type

Tags: typescript

Why is `example` in `function g` unable to interpret the type? It regards it as `any`

```
function f (name : string) {
    return {
        name : name,
    }
}

function g (name : string) {
    return {
        ...f(name),
        get example () {
            return this.name + " example";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a work around without forcing the output type? e.g. `get example () : string`

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMRAKMBDAtgU0QLkQGcoAnGMAcwEpEBvAKEWcVJyhFKUZd8U1wF%202HABomLAL4NpDUJFgJElNALyES5KrR4s2HLvQl9EAOnPB0I6uJPNK7RDgAe2AA4AbPKh3G7zfU4kKAALGCJTNUQAakQAIidXLE8cOIBuP15pLJkgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution (maybe just work around) is to create a variable for the other function and use that instead of `this`

```
function f (name : string) {
    return {
        name : name,
    }
}

function g (name : string) {
    const toMerge = f(name)
    return {
        ...toMerge,
        get example () {
            return toMerge.name + " example";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a Bug in TypeScript.

I was able to reduce the example further ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gKBpmA6X6sExgCGAtgKYwBcMARAGYgi0A0GWAvmwQObmzk4ZAA4AbSgAoAlKnaEYAegBUMAORhVMAJakxW4FqiiAnjAAWxCDCjHhlVcTDHNAI3LBiAVwiVDMACYg5FZgILAWAG6UxNa20WChUMRQWuAwjv7aVgBO5PTkuWDA5Jn+WrnARqYg2dpgZRVVddpQViAA7mB1hlrEoloAXgXYEgDsAAwATJMySgpyhKCQsF3IUGZaENgkFADciioSwtkgdtk2MjvkNNDZWmA8MHMLBMowS9BENI6mzy9YuSgnmyXTAuwWXAWfCgghE4hg0lk8kwHxWSGsGy2V3ByJggOBoJxnDYHF2QA)):

```
const x = {
    ...{
        name : "foo",
    },
    get example () {
        /* 'n' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022) */
        const n = this.name; /* (property) name: string */
        /* const n: any */

        return n;
    },
    getexample () {
        const n = this.name;
        return n;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @htho I realized my initial answer was not right, the problem seems to be with the spread operator, by changing to the following the error will be gone:

```
//...
function g (name : string) {
    return {
        name: f(name).name,
        get example () {
            return this.name + " example";
        }
    }
}

console.log(g("John"))
```

Even if you set the return type for the getter as string (`get example():string ...`) and run a `console.log(g("John"))` in TS playground, you will see that `this.name` will return undefined and not working as expected.

I would refactor your code to the following, it would be more readable and simpler to understand by other developers:

```
class Person {
    name: string

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    get example() {
        return this.name + " example"
    }
}
function g(name: string) {
    return new Person(name)
}

console.log(g("John").example)
```

Comment: Yes turning this into a class is the way to go. But that would mean, that getters on object would generally not work - but according to the examples on MDN they do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_getters_and_setters
The trick is to set the target in tsconfig to ESNext - then the getters work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Typescript is "nice" with you when inferring the type but because hashMap are not process in the order they have been declared, we cannot know for sure the `f(name)` will be executed before `get example()`.

Therefore you must be sure the function `f` is executed before, eg

```
function f(name: string) {
  return {
    name: name,
  };
}

function g(name: string) {
  const res = {...f(name)}

  return {
    name: res.name,
    get example() {
      return this.name + " example";
    }
  };
}

console.log(g("Max").example); // "Max example"
```

And it is not a bug since the result of `this.name` will yield "undefined" if called when you are destructuring the function in your original exemple.

```js
function f(name: string) {
  return {
    name: name,
  };
}

function g(name: string) {
  return {
    ...f(name),
    get example() {
      return this.name + " example";
    }
  };
}

console.log(g("Max").example); // "undefined example"
```

Edit: after some researches, it seems that the problems comes from the spread operator that cannot mutate an object as Object.assign will do [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

Therefore this will works even in typescript complains:

```
function f(name: string) {
  return { name: name }
}

function g(name: string) {
  const obj1 = { get example() {return this.name + " example"}};
  return Object.assign(obj1, f(name))
}

console.log(g("Max").example); // "Max example"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the return to example and access the correct element of f functio. I did the interface of the return too, but is optional. Look the exemple:

```js
// interface to return of F function

interface ReturnFName {
    name: string;
}

function f (name : string): ReturnFName {
    return {
        name : name,
    }
}

function g (name : string) {
    // get the element name and store it in a variable
    const nameF = f(name).name;
    return {
        get example (): string {
            return nameF+ " example";
        }
    }
}

console.log(g('carol'));
```

Run the code on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrU0D2p62gK7yShaKgBioiBkq04WkAUM1HEmhgEr5GQUAcsgC2GAN7NQoSKNgAuUAGdo8KAHMA3MwC%20rGnQZNqAClljFKtZHUBKRb0LEhc0JOl4nJd9JlzF5rAANFKgOtp6zAb0jCTqZv7Kqhq2bqEgoOr4mAAWGLAANrBiMH5ioMiQACZJWHgQ0BAkyKAAbshqyABGRaGoTCplsFQAvKaBtgB0gdoefMRpvpnZsAAeogAORSb2Sdbqi0u48ySBVADUoABEoGubRVezvjoh0uG6rP2QSlhFkwVYeLxK6oDq-K62WzaIA)